# Why isn't my code running before the interval completes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the snippet, I want the color of `timer` to change to red *before* the `alert` pops up.

I have written `$("#timer").css('color', 'red');` before `alert("Time Up!")`, so logically it should change the text color before showing the alert, but it is changing color after displaying the alert.

```js
let time = 3;

$(function() {
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    time--;
    
    if (time >= 0)
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time + "";
    else {
      $("#timer").css('color', 'red');
      clearInterval(interval);
      alert("Time Up!")
    }
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="timer">3</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `alert()` blocks the UI from updating, and although you call `css()` *before* `alert()`, there's not enough time to update the DOM before the alert appears and temporarily prevents any further rendering.

To fix this, place the `alert()` call in a timeout with a short delay. This allows the UI to be updated before the `alert()` is displayed:

```js
let time = 3;

jQuery($ => {
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    time--;
    
    if (time >= 0) {
      $("#timer").html(time);
    } else {
      $("#timer").css('color', 'red');
      clearInterval(interval);
      setTimeout(() => alert("Time Up!"), 0);
    }
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="timer">3</h1>
```